# Get ArrayList Value?

Tags: java

In below code

`queryCmisAdvance.getAdvanceKeywords()` returns ArrayList of class AdvancePropertyKeywords

In Class AdvancePropertyKeywords

there are Three Parameter `String Property Name , condition and value.`

Some time it is possible that value can be "" (and this is not null)

**and now i want to retrive the propertyName whose value is not "" .**

My code

```
   for(AdvancePropertyKeywords apk : queryCmisAdvance.getAdvanceKeywords()){

                if (apk.getValue()!="" ) {
                    System.out.println(apk.getPropertyName() +" " +apk.getCondition() + " "+apk.getValue());
                }
            }
```

**outPut**

```
From =   

SentOn > Wed Aug 22 12:00:00 UTC+2 2012 

EmailSubject LIKE folder 

DocumentTitle NULL rgftre  

CarbonCopy LIKE
```

---

```
From value is "" 

SentOn value is Wed Aug 22 12:00:00 UTC+2 2012

EmailSubject value is folder 

DocumentTitle value is rgftre 

CarbonCopy value is ""
```

Comment: Don't compare Strings with "!=". Use .equals(). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DanGravell   : thanks , this works.

```
if (!(apk.getValue().equals(""))) {
                System.out.println(apk.getPropertyName() +" " +apk.getCondition() + " "+apk.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals()` method instead of `!=` operator. `equals()` method compares object contents while `==` and `!=` operators compare `object reference values` in case of `Object Comparision`. See following code :

```
for(AdvancePropertyKeywords apk : queryCmisAdvance.getAdvanceKeywords()){
     if (!"".equals(apk.getValue()) {
         System.out.println(apk.getPropertyName() +" " +apk.getCondition() + " "+apk.getValue());
     }
}
```

Comment: i need not equal to..neway thanks.. I found the solution.